# Polymer, send variable i am setting into another element

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to toggle different events by a string which I am setting between 2 animated pages

I have some code coming back up onto the page holding both animated pages that swaps and sets the id I want to send like so

```
_onElementClick: function(event) {
            this.$.dataId = event.detail.data.id;
            this.$.pages.selected = 1;
        },
```

so the pages.selected changes the page perfectly fine, and if I log this.$.dataId it is the correct value, howeber on this page i am trying to pass this.$.dataId into another element like so

```
 <my-polymer-full dataId="dataId"></my-polymer-full>
```

and use it in the element like

```
 <div>[[dataId]]</div>
```

and in the element I have it set like

```
     properties: {
        dataId: {
            type: String
        },
```

and this does not seem to work. I am new to polymer and unsure what I am doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using node selectors, `this.$`, when trying to use properties. Instead, consider setting property values on the element itself like:

```
_onElementClick: function(event) {
  this.dataId = event.detail.data.id;
  this.$.pages.selected = 1;
}
```

Then use one or two-way data-binding to bind those properties to the properties of the elements you want to use them in like:

```
 <my-polymer-full data-id="[[dataId]]"></my-polymer-full>
```

Importantly, note the use of `data-id`. This is how you need to represent camelCase properties published by any custom Polymer element. That was probably your main issue originally.

Comment: Hey @Ricky , thanks! This worked like a charm, I'm just learning polymer. Would you happen to know of a place where I could read/learn more about this? I looked through their 1.0 documentation and did not see this, but it's entirely possible I missed this. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome! The docs don't disclaim this behaviour as much as it should but it's in there if you look hard enough - "To bind to camel-case properties of elements, use dash-case in the attribute name" See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-binding.